# Migrate from Linux Mint to OS X

Tags: linux-mint, osx, settings, migration, dot-files

So my trusty Linux box died after 10 years of faithful service.  The memorial will be Friday afternoon.

Anyway, I am moving to a Mac (lesser of two evils - a Win 10 machine was the other option), and I don't think I want to run Linux on it directly - I booted with a live cd of Mint 18 and the video resolution was wonky and no extra drivers to install.  So OS X it is.

My issue is that I've got LOTS of settings, etc. for various apps (all cross platform - firefox, thunderbird, geany, filezilla, virtualbox, netbeans, android studio, etc) that I'd like to move over as well.  I've pulled the drive my /home directory was on, so I have all of the files.

Some things are trivial - my ssh private keys and config file for connecting to various hosts still go in `~/.ssh`

But most of the other apps I can't find where to put my data/settings/preferences/profile files.  Where do these go on OS X? I opened terminal and looked in my home directory, there is no `~/.mozilla` or `~/.filezilla` etc directory.

Comment: "Where do I find these" is on-topic here, but "where do I put them" probably isn't. [apple.se] might be more suitable, but this looks a bit broad at the moment in any case ("where do I put settings for various apps, etc?").

Comment: @MichaelHomer - so "Where does Netbeans keep its user specific configuration on OS X" is ok, and "I have a copy of my Netbeans user-specific settings, where do I put it on my new OS X machine" isn't?  Huh... who woulda thunk

Comment: I'm not sure that would be ok either. The [help/on-topic] lists the scope as "The Unix foundation underlying OS X (but generally *not* frontend application questions)". Where settings are stored on macOS is more a frontend application question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OS X, there is a hidden directory `~/Library`, whose subdirectories will contain that kind of user settings. This is for historical reasons: it is similar to pre-OS X versions of MacOS used to do.

Here is a MozillaZine KB article that has the exact paths for Firefox on Windows, Linux and Mac:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox

Comment: I think the ~/Library may work - is this the standard place for preferences if I'm not seeing the traditional ~/.appname directories?

Comment: Yes, it's the standard for native Mac-style programs. Unix-style programs that have been ported to Mac OS X may still use the traditional Unix conventions.

Comment: Actually some other directories under ~/Library, but this got me working.